How to remove insecticide overspray from objects
I was spraying Kingtox spray (active ingredients: meperfluthrin, esbiothrin, permethrin, cypermethrin) and mistakenly sprayed on wall clock as well. Question is it harmful later on if somebody touches the clock? If yes then how to clean the clock so it does not contain any harmful chemical.

What instructions/warnings does the label provide?

Metofluthrin and all of the other active ingredients are all pyrethroids, which are the safest of all insecticides. It's basically the same ingredient used to treat lice in children all over the world, including the US and Europe. So yes, it's safe to the touch. Just wipe it away.

Kingtox spray is apparently an insecticide, according to Google. Is it dangerous? Probably, in some amount. If the can has a Warning on it, it's dangerous in some way.
Read the can to see if it shows clean-up instructions, then follow them.
If no clean-up instructions are given, and you can't find anything on Kingtox's websites, try this:
Most sprayable things may be water or oil based. Both might be cleaned off with soap. I would try wiping the clock down with a disposable cloth reasonably wet with grease-cutting dishwashing soap and water. (Unplug the clock if it is plug-in.) The soap should remove water-based spray and cut through oil-based spray, allowing the water to remove the residue.
Wipe dry with another cloth, then inspect the surface to see if there are any drips of the insecticide still visible. Repeat until the spray drops are all gone.
Let the clock dry off, especially if it is plug-in.

If the can has a Warning on it, it's dangerous in some way. Technically true. But doesn't mean much - have you heard of Proposition 65? That being said, this spray is certainly dangerous in a measurable way - or else it wouldn't be terribly effective on pests.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Prop 65: "Everything under the sun is known to the State of California to cause cancer." :) True, Some warnings suffer from alarm fatigue...

Alcohol (e.g. 91% isopropyl alcohol) is a universal solvent, and no additional water is needed. Dries quickly, too.
